is webtrader.xtprofit.net Legit
I had opened an account a few week ago with Xtprofit platform. I test some transactions with a litte amount, and it works.
But there are some security issues:
1- I can't activate two factor authentication (2FA)
2- I can't add fishing code
3- All transaction withdrawal and deposit pass throw an non identified adress. For example, within my account, I can't see my bitcoin address to receive external money, and withdrawal is complicated and must done by the advisor financial.
When I ask for those issues, the support team told me they are an investing company and not a cryptocurrency exchange. All transactions of deposit and withdrawal should done with my advisor financial.
The company has its phone contact and adress in London.
It easy to see that information in their web site: https://www.xtprofit.net/contact-us
Is anyone here had an experience with this company?
Is this a scam platform investment?


xtptofit.com only recently created  2. No UK limited company or PLC registered with that name 3. 40 Bank street probably has thousands of different occupants - many different businesses offer offices to let there as well as virtual offices - a good place to falsely claim as an address. Especially if you omit the floor number and office number.

